# Managing resource files with cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods

I want to add a file `help.rtf` to `MyPod`, in such a way that

- when I import `MyPod` to my project, the file `help.rtf` will be copied (so that I have a easy access to this file) to the `Pods/`directory of my project
- `help.rtf` is not added to the resources of my application (it does not appear in the list `Copy Bundle resources`, in the `Build Phases` of the targets)

Is it possible to do that?

---

EDIT

*My answer to the question "are you trying to add some resources to your library?".*

Yes, I want to add a "resource" to my library **but** a resource that will not be copied in the application: a resource that will only be available in the list of files of the projet. I would like to be able to read the `.rtf` from the files navigator of my project, but I would like to exclude the file from the "built resources".

Comment: just to clarify the intention, are you trying to add some resources to your library?

Comment: See my edit, I hope I clarified the question enough.